# Shorten code to perform search based on four slash-delimited parameters

Tags: c#, strings

How can I make this code more compact?

It is a ASP.net WebForms project

It is a SinglePageApplication for searching in list mode and map mode.

I have many paths for a page.

- /Denmark
- /Denmark/Copenhagen
- /Denmark/Copenhagen/Christiansborg
- Map/Denmark
- Map/Denmark/Copenhagen
- Map/Denmark/Copenhagen/Christiansborg

in which that control the UI and parameteres passed to a JavaScript function

```
string parameters = (string)Page.RouteData.Values["params"],
    param1 = string.Empty,
        param2 = string.Empty,
            param3 = string.Empty,
                param4 = string.Empty;

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parameters))
{
    var parameterArray = parameters.Split('/');
    var i = 0;
    while (i < parameterArray.Length)
    {
        if (i == 3)
            param4 = parameterArray[3];

        if (i == 2)
            param3 = parameterArray[2];

        if (i == 1)
            param2 = parameterArray[1];

        if (i == 0)
            param1 = parameterArray[0];

        i++;
    }
}


SearchState = new RoomSearchState(param1, param2, param3, param4);
```

And the RoomStateSearch

```
public RoomSearchState(string param1, string param2, string param3, string param4)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(param1))
    {
        if (param1.Equals("Kort", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            ViewType = "Map";

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(param2) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(param3) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(param4))
            {
                Country = param2.ToUnfriendlyUrl();
                Area = param3.ToUnfriendlyUrl();
                SubArea = param4.ToUnfriendlyUrl();
                SearchType = SearchStateType.Address;
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(param2) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(param3))
            {
                SearchType = param2.StartsWith("@") ? SearchStateType.Coordinates : SearchStateType.Address;
                Area = param3.ToUnfriendlyUrl();
                Country = param2.ToUnfriendlyUrl();
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(param2) && param2.StartsWith("@"))
            {
                SearchType = SearchStateType.Coordinates;
                Area = param2;
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(param2))
            {
                SearchType = SearchStateType.Address;
                Area = param2.ToUnfriendlyUrl();
            }
            else
            {
                SearchType = SearchStateType.Empty;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ViewType = "Default";

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(param1) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(param2) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(param3))
            {
                Country = param1.ToUnfriendlyUrl();
                Area = param3.ToUnfriendlyUrl();
                SearchType = SearchStateType.Address;
                SubArea = param2.ToUnfriendlyUrl();
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(param1) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(param2))
            {
                Area = param2.ToUnfriendlyUrl();
                SearchType = SearchStateType.Address;
                Country = param1.ToUnfriendlyUrl();
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(param1) && param1.StartsWith("@"))
            {
                SearchType = SearchStateType.Coordinates;
                Area = param1;
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(param1))
            {
                SearchType = SearchStateType.Address;
                Area = param1.ToUnfriendlyUrl();
            }
            else
            {
                SearchType = SearchStateType.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        SearchType = SearchStateType.Empty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code doesn't look like much fun at all

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parameters))
{
    var parameterArray = parameters.Split('/');
    var i = 0;
    while (i < parameterArray.Length)
    {
        if (i == 3)
            param4 = parameterArray[3];

        if (i == 2)
            param3 = parameterArray[2];

        if (i == 1)
            param2 = parameterArray[1];

        if (i == 0)
            param1 = parameterArray[0];

        i++;
    }
}
```

you should have a string array called `param` and fill it with the parameters you need.

```
var parameterArray = parameters.Split('/');
var param = new string[4];

for (int i = 0; i < parameterArray.Length; i++) {
    param[i] = parameterArray[i];
}

SearchState = new RoomSearchState(param[0], param[1], param[2], param[3]);
```

This is much simpler than what you were doing and makes a good use of a string array

---

in `RoomStateSearch`  your nested if statements are horribly redundant.

You should look at the logic and see what you can combine  in the first set you come to you repeat `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(param2)` in the conditional statement when it should be it's own if statement that houses everything restricted by this condition.

Same thing with the second (big) if statement block only the condition is `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(param1)`

Comment: I got it working with: `var param = new string[4];`

Comment: @Marc-Andre, OP already assigns an Empty String value to each index of the Parameter array by assigning it in the `parameters` string.

Comment: I have updated my answer.. :)

Comment: @Malachi You can just use the [`Array.Resize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051(v=vs.110).aspx) to expand it. The empty area will be filled with `null` which will fail the `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` test.

Comment: @Marc-Andre the OP starts out with a 4 element array merged into a string, then takes the string apart into a 4 element array, there will always be a 4 element array the way that the OP has it written.

Answer (score 7):

### Code Structure

- It is quite tedious what you trying to do in the first piece of code. You might as well just pass the string array directly. As accessing an indexed element is not much different than variable named like `paramx`.
- The second piece of code is mirrored from the middle. The lower section and upper section are essentially doing the same job with only 1 offset in parameter, and `ViewType` being different.
- Never repeatedly make the same test, if possibly. Try to process by reduction and elimination, or change the flow of code.

### Logic Flaws

- When only one argument or two arguments (that begins with `"Map"` or  `"Kort"`) are passed, then `Area` is being assigned instead of `Country`.

  ```
  else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(param1))
  {
      SearchType = SearchStateType.Address;
      Area = param1.ToUnfriendlyUrl();
  }
  ```
- When 3 or 4(with Map/Kort) arguments are passed, `SubArea` is assigned before `Area`.

  ```
  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(param1) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(param2) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(param3))
  {
      Country = param1.ToUnfriendlyUrl();
      Area = param3.ToUnfriendlyUrl();
      SearchType = SearchStateType.Address;
      SubArea = param2.ToUnfriendlyUrl();
  }
  ```

---

### Polished Code

```
SearchState = new RoomSearchState(parameters.Split('/'))
```

```
public RoomSearchState()
{
    SearchType = SearchStateType.Empty;
    ViewType = "Default";
}

public RoomSearchState(string[] args) : this()
{
    if (!args.Any()) return;

    if (args[0] == "Kort" || args[0] == "Map")
    {
        ViewType = "Map";
        args = args.Skip(1).ToArray();
    }

    switch(args.Length)
    {
        case 1:
            if (args[0].StartsWith("@"))
            {
                Country = args[0];
                SearchType = SearchStateType.Coordinates;
            }
            else
            {
                Country = args[0].ToUnfriendlyUrl();
                SearchType = SearchStateType.Address;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            Country = args[0].ToUnfriendlyUrl();
            Area = args[1].ToUnfriendlyUrl();
            SearchType = SearchStateType.Address;
            break;
        case 3:
            Country = args[0].ToUnfriendlyUrl();
            Area = args[1].ToUnfriendlyUrl();
            SubArea = args[2].ToUnfriendlyUrl();
            SearchType = SearchStateType.Address;
            break;
        default: throw new ArgumentException("args");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe nobody has suggested using regular expressions?
I'm not too familiar with ASP.NET but I've done development in JavaScript.

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches( "/?(\w+)/?", parameters );
```

Then you can use matches as the parameter array.

*** Note I don't have the ability to test this

Comment: I did use regular expressions on the client-side to handle pushState, but went away from it because it was not very easy to mange changes to

Comment: @TryingToImprove I'm not sure what you mean by "not very easy to manage changes", care to elaborate? :)

Comment: @h4unt3r, elaborating that Regex is Regex.  now you have 2 problems the original and the Regex.  there is no reason for the regex  the code is able to separate the parameters based on a single delimiter `/` and the inputted parameters are already in the format they need to be, Regex would make this code less readable in my opinion.

Comment: @h4unt3r What Malachi says.. aaaand I am not very good to regex.. ;) But I like the idea of using regex